# Why the following code in class "test" don't give stackoverflow error with static keyword

Tags: java, class, object, static

Why the following code in class `test` don't give stackoverflow error with `static` keyword?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        test t = new test();
          
    }
}
```

```
class test{

    static  test p = new test() ;  
}
```

Comment: Because `p` is static.

Comment: @Amongalen without static it gives stackoverflow that i know b'se of infinite object creation but why not with static.

Comment: What do you think the static keyword does? If you explain that, you will probably see why  the behaviour is as it is.

Comment: @tgdavies got it

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer

1. static variables in a class are initialized before any object of that class can be created.

2)static variables,methods are related to class rather than a particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

as p is static - it is initialized only once, so new test() won't be executed a second time - thus no stack overflow

Comment: "as p is static - it is initialized only once, so new test() won't be executed a second time"
can you elaborate on that please.